# Complicated bridge between 2 servers

Tags: ip, ipv4, network, ipsec, bridge

I have 3 servers:
comp_a, comp_b, comp_c

```
comp_a ([eth0 «10.15.14.55»]) 10.0.0.0/8 <———> comp_b ([eth0 «10.15.27.61», eth1 «10.15.26.61»] [eth1 «10.15.26.61» ]) <——VPN IPS (left = 10.15.0.0/16 right = 192.168.21.152/30 )——> comp_c 192.168.0.0/16  ([eth1 «192.168.21.153» ])
```

comp_b:
`ip r`

```
default via 10.15.26.1 dev eth1 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.15.27.1 dev eth0 
10.15.26.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.15.26.61 
10.15.27.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.15.27.61
```

What needs to be achieved:

1. 192.168.21.153 (comp_c) should be able to ping the entire internal network 10.15.0.0/16, including 10.15.14.55.
2. Pings from network 10.15.0.0/16 to 10.15.27.61 (comp_b [eth0]) should go to 192.168.21.153 (comp_c).
   This way servers from the 10.15.0.0/16 network would actually work with 192.168.21.153, although they used IP 10.15.27.61 instead.

How do I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All that should be accomplished with using static routes. Note that any gateway needs to be part of a subnet that the host is connected to. However, host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. For an on-topic business network you might want to try on [sf] or on [su] otherwise.

Comment: Build a network with cables, switches and routers that connect the various networks or use a VPN connection between the various networks to allow them to connect.